# XeLaTeX Unicode symbols do not show up in verbatim

Tags: xetex, unicode

The following snippet produces the desired result outside of the verbatim block, but not within the verbatim block.  I guess I have to specify a font for verbatim mode that contains support for the symbols codepage.

Can someone help me out -- how do I do this, and perhaps with a good font suggestion?

Snippet:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
ext:  ".☃"
\begin{verbatim}
stem: "föõbår"
ext:  ".☃"
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set as mono font a font that has the symbol:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
ext:  ".☃"
\begin{verbatim}
stem: "föõbår"
ext:  ".☃"
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]